# Gradle in Android Studio requires HTTPS connections

Tags: android, maven, android-studio, gradle

I have a very old project using Android Studio 0.5.

When I try to compile the project, I get the following message:

```
Failed to refresh Gradle project 'project': Could not GET 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/'. Received status code 501 from server: HTTPS Required
```

Before that message it also output that I can enable de offline mode in order to avoid gradle to connect to the internet. I enable that mode but the message contiue appearing (but this time, does not appears the part relation to offline mode).

I suppose that the URL (`http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/`) is specified in a file and changing that URL to use https instead of http solve the problem but I can't figure out where is the file that contains the URL.

In which file that URL is defined? (I can't update Android Studio)

Answer (score 2):

Search the URL http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/ in your code and change it to https

Comment: The only thing I have is `classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'` in my gradle file  :(

Answer (score 1):

I bumped into a similar problem, I'm using Gradle on the command line. I executed `gradle init` and then `gradle wrapper` to generate a `gradlew` wrapper in the project directory. At that point `./gradlew jar` complains about HTTP vs HTTPS as shown in the problem statement above.

I was able to fix it by editing the `build.gradle` file, which, I gather, was generated by either `gradle init` or `gradle wrapper`, since it doesn't appear to be a project file. I changed

```
    maven {
        url = uri('http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2')
    }
```

to

```
    maven {
        url = uri('https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2')
    }
```

and when I tried `./gradlew jar` again, the error went away.